# Why does bind(..) for ipv6 under mac os x give me error number 47

Tags: c++, macos, sockets

I am taking first steps in socket programming as an added complexity I am trying to use ipv6:

Shouldn't this:

```
struct sockaddr_in6* addr = new sockaddr_in6;
int s = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
addr->sin6_addr = in6addr_any;
addr->sin6_port = 1234;
int ret = bind(s, (struct sockaddr*)addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6));
```

bind a socket to all interfaces on my machine to port 1234?
trouble is bind returns -1 and errno is 47
which according to errno.h is:

```
#define EAFNOSUPPORT    47              /* Address family not supported by protocol 
family */
```

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set addr->sin6_family to AF_INET6 or at least zero-initialise the address structure  before passing it to bind().